# pandas json_normalize columns created as dtype object

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json object served from an api as follows:

```
{
  "workouts": [
    {
      "id": 92527291,
      "starts": "2021-06-28T15:42:44.000Z",
      "minutes": 30,
      "name": "Indoor Cycling",
      "created_at": "2021-06-28T16:12:57.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-28T16:12:57.000Z",
      "plan_id": null,
      "workout_token": "ELEMNT BOLT A1B3:59",
      "workout_type_id": 12,
      "workout_summary": {
        "id": 87540207,
        "heart_rate_avg": "152.0",
        "calories_accum": "332.0",
        "created_at": "2021-06-28T16:12:58.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-06-28T16:12:58.000Z",
        "power_avg": "185.0",
        "distance_accum": "17520.21",
        "cadence_avg": "87.0",
        "ascent_accum": "0.0",
        "duration_active_accum": "1801.0",
        "duration_paused_accum": "0.0",
        "duration_total_accum": "1801.0",
        "power_bike_np_last": "186.0",
        "power_bike_tss_last": "27.6",
        "speed_avg": "9.73",
        "work_accum": "332109.0",
        "file": {
          "url": "https://cdn.wahooligan.com/wahoo-cloud/production/uploads/workout_file/file/FPoJBPZo17BvTmSomq5Y_Q/2021-06-28-154244-ELEMNT_BOLT_A1B3-59-0.fit"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "total": 55,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 1,
  "order": "descending",
  "sort": "starts"
}
```

I want to get the data into a dataframe. However, lots of the columns seem to have a dtype of object.  I assume that this is because some of the numeric values in the json are double quoted. What is the best and most efficient way to avoid this (the json potentially has many workouts elements)?

Is it to fix the returned json? Or to iterate through the dataframe columns and convert the objects to floats?

Thank you

Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas.to_numeric.  Here are the docs.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: I tried     for col in df:
        df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='ignore') and that has converted the quoted numbers to numbers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, meta=[
                  'total', 'page', 'per_page', 'order', 'sort'], record_path='workouts').convert_dtypes()
```